# Merge SQL queries with shell scripting

Tags: mysql, shell

I made a small code of SQL queries, with some of shell scripting in one file, I am stuck how to jump from a command line to a SQL query, the second query does NOT run:

file.sh

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE << QUERY_INPUT

SELECT ip FROM ban_ip;

QUERY_INPUT

ls -l << QUERY_INPUT // Until here is good,
SELECT ip FROM ban_ip; // This command line does NOT run

QUERY_INPUT
```

UPDATED answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Connect to DB and select ban_ip
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DB -e 'SELECT ip INTO OUTFILE “/var/lib/mysql/ip2ban.txt" FROM ban_ip WHERE ip_tables = "0"';

# After the Select query we need to move the file
mv /var/lib/mysql/ip2ban.txt /root/Scripts/IPTables/autoBan/ip2ban.txt


mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DB -e 'UPDATE ban_ip SET ip_tables = "1" WHERE ip_tables = "0"';

echo -e "Database updated with new banned IPs on $Now \nThank you for using this script" 2>&1 | sed '1!b;s/^/To: my_e_mail@gmail.com\nSubject: New banned IPs\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HEREDOC format](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) uses a marker to indicate the end of input; in your case you've used `QUERY_INPUT` as a delimiter. In the first instance you are passing a query to `mysql` but in the second for some reason you are passing the input to `ls -l`.

Anyway, you don't need to use HEREDOC at all, just use `-e` parameter to `mysql`:

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE -e 'SELECT ip FROM ban_ip'
```

Comment: Am I going to do like this `mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE -e 'SELECT ip FROM ban_ip'` then second line `ls -l` then third line again `mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE -e 'SELECT ip FROM ban_ip'`

Comment: I updated with the new answer, if you could check if it is correct or not

Comment: Looks reasonable. If you're having troubles with it, please open a new question.

Comment: No troubles, I am trying to develop it to log any error in a log file